# Update TextBlock during function (syncronous) in .NET core

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, textblock

I am making a small program with .NET Core and I there is somenthing I don't know how to implement: I want to update a textblock in my GUI during a function which may take quite a long time. It is not asynchronous and I have just one thread. My XAML is:

```
<mah:MetroWindow x:Class="MyProgram.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProgram"
        xmlns:mah="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="My Title" Height="550" Width="850" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Dosis, Verdana, Comic Sans MS" >

    <Grid>
        <!-- Grid Rows and Column Definitions -->
        
        <!-- Fields in the UI -->

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Name="lblStatusTxtBlk" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10 30" Text="{Binding lblStatus, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

    </Grid>
</mah:MetroWindow>
```

In the UI there is a button which calls a function, during this function I would like to show some infos for the user like "step 1 completed", "step 2 in progress", etc; I do not want nor need a detailed update, just something to give the idea of what is happening.
The XAML.CS is:

```
// List of using instructions 

namespace MyProgram
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //Bunch of variables    
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;

            lblStatus = "Start";
        }

        #region GETTER - SETTER
        private String _lblStatus = "1";
        public String lblStatus
        {
            get
            {
                return _lblStatus;
            }
            set
            {
                _lblStatus = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("lblStatus");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion

        private void printValues(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            //Step 1 of printValues;
            lblStatus = "End of Step 1, start step 2";
            //Step 2 of printValues;
            lblStatus = "End of Step 2, start step 3";
            //Step 3 of printValues;
            lblStatus = "End of Step 3, start step 4";
            //Step 4 of printValues;

            //Print final report ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I start the program I read "start" in the text block, so I can say the binding works. However, when the function is running the TextBlock is not updated until the end and not every step. I am not getting any error or warning, nor at compile time nor at runtime. How can I solve?

Comment: "It is not asynchronous and I have just one thread" I suspect this is your problem. Even though `PropertyChanged()` is presumably firing, if your UI thread is tied up elsewhere it probably won't update UI components until it's finished. I expect your UI is also sluggish... this is _exactly_ the sort of thing `async` code is designed to improve and you should probably be using it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably *should* be using a different thread for your long running task (this is the sort of thing it's intended for)! I expect if you do, updates will appear when you expect and your UI should be more responsive too.

Progress can be sent back to the UI thread using the `Progress<T>` class which implements the `IProgress<T>` interface, both found in `System`.

Rather than modify your example into a working program, for brevity I've put together a console version:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var progReporter = new Progress<int>(o => Report(o));
            await Task.Run(() => LongProcess(progReporter));

            Console.WriteLine("Task Complete");
        }

        private static void Report(int progress)
            => Console.WriteLine($"{progress}% completed");

        private static void LongProcess(IProgress<int> progReporter)
        {
            // Step 1...
            Thread.Sleep(300);
            progReporter.Report(25);
            // Step 2...
            Thread.Sleep(300);
            progReporter.Report(50);
            // Step 3...
            Thread.Sleep(300);
            progReporter.Report(75);
            // Step 4...
            Thread.Sleep(300);
            progReporter.Report(100);
        }
    }
}
```

The only important thing to note is that the lambda passed to `progReporter` captures the context of the main thread - what would be the UI thread in a GUI program - so it's important to define it on the main thread and not inside `LongProcress()` or anywhere else called by `Task.Run()`. Obviously, your lambda will update `lblStatus`.

Note also that the task sometimes completes before the last update is displayed - make sure your UI can cope with that eventuality cleanly.

There's a good write-up of the techniques on the MSDN blog: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/